# Must openSessionWithAllowLoginUI only when click Facebook login button in iOS

Tags: ios, authentication, ios7, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.1

After implementing  Facebook login with success in iOS, I need now to call the loginUI only when the user click on the login button. I do not know the right place in my code to call the openSessionWithAllowLoginUI method. I have placed it at viewDidLoad, but it calls the loginUI without user click and don't want this. Anyone?

Comment: Did not find answer. Can you explain me it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many possible solutions to handle the login button, I found the better way to do this. Had implemented my own button with the same appearance of the original button and attached the action.